# UITextField "text" property setter in Swift

Tags: swift, properties, uitextfield, setter

How I can apply some actions when user/developer set value for "text" property (UITextField object) in code or in storyboard. How I can detect changing core property?

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is:

```
override public var text : String? {
    didSet {
        // Do whatever you want, for example
        if !(text != nil && text!.isEmpty) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add explanation, where this code should be added, how to use it?

Comment: @MrugeshTank It can be added in your personal UITextField subclass (you can see `override` keyword here - it means that your class changes behavior of its superclass)

Answer (score 3):

You can add an observer for key path text to your textfield than implement observeValueForKeyPath method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTextField.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text", options: .New, context: nil)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {


    let newText = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as String

    // add your action here

}

deinit{

    myTextField.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create an Outlet for your textfield and a IBAction for Sent Events Editing Changed.

```
@IBOutlet weak var strText: UITextField!

@IBAction func editedAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    // do whatever
    // strText.text = "whatever"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx, for comment. But I need add action when you set value. Ex: strText.text = "Test" and my method called. Principle similar like "get/set" to normal property, but I need apply this to stored property.

Answer (score 0):

In swift...

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

 @objc func textDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
     // DO something with textField.text
 }
```